# Arcscan greyed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcscan

the Arcscan toolbar is greyed out.

1. The Arcscan extension is enabled.
2. The raster is a "bi-level" image
3. There is an editable polyline layer in the ArcMap TOC

Do you have any idea why i still can't use ArcScan?

1. Edit:
   Edit session was started.
   Unique Value was set.
   [image]

Still not enabled.

@mr.adam how can i check the binary classification? I used copy raster and set the pixel type to 1_BIT

Do I have to consider any other settings?

Comment: First step is to double-check the binary classification and to have an edit session open.

Comment: use Copy Raster (Data Management http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000 make sure the output image is tiff 1 bit (0 or 1)

Comment: Make sure the ArcScan extension is activated; under Customize > Extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Your raster classification is incorrect. You need to change the symbology to either 'Unique Values' or 'Classified', doing this will enable your ArcScan toolbar.

> Right click layer > Layer properties > Symbology tab> "Unique Values" or "Classified"

***ArcScan tool bar WILL NOT enable with 'Stretched' or 'Discrete Color' symbolization.

***ArcScan tool bar WILL enable with 'Unique Values' or 'Classified' symbolization.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it was already set to unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Check this help info from ESRI. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007637

I was having the same problem. I changed the symbology to classified with two categorize and it works.